# Mobile capability for installing app to iOS device

Tags: appium

Can one install an iOS app during the Appium driver initialization, because I'm not seeing a mobile capability for this.

https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/remote/MobileCapabilityType.html

I suppose "app" is it but I don't see it in the actual class

```
package io.appium.java_client.remote;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;

public interface IOSMobileCapabilityType extends CapabilityType {

    /**
     * (Sim-only) Calendar format to set for the iOS Simulator.
     */
    String CALENDAR_FORMAT = "calendarFormat";

    /**
     * Bundle ID of the app under test. Useful for starting an app on a real device
     * or for using other caps which require the bundle ID during test startup.
     * To run a test on a real device using the bundle ID,
     * you may omit the 'app' capability, but you must provide 'udid'.
     */
    String BUNDLE_ID = "bundleId";

    /**
     * Amount of time in ms to wait for instruments before assuming it hung and
     * failing the session.
     */
    String LAUNCH_TIMEOUT = "launchTimeout";

    /**
     * (Sim-only) Force location services to be either on or off.
     * Default is to keep current sim setting.
     */
    String LOCATION_SERVICES_ENABLED = "locationServicesEnabled";

    /**
     * (Sim-only) Set location services to be authorized or not authorized for app via plist,
     * so that location services alert doesn't pop up. Default is to keep current sim
     * setting. Note that if you use this setting you MUST also use the bundleId
     * capability to send in your app's bundle ID.
     */
    String LOCATION_SERVICES_AUTHORIZED = "locationServicesAuthorized";

    /**
     * Accept all iOS alerts automatically if they pop up.
     * This includes privacy access permission alerts
     * (e.g., location, contacts, photos). Default is false.
     */
    String AUTO_ACCEPT_ALERTS = "autoAcceptAlerts";

    /**
     * Dismiss all iOS alerts automatically if they pop up.
     * This includes privacy access permission alerts (e.g.,
     * location, contacts, photos). Default is false.
     */
    String AUTO_DISMISS_ALERTS = "autoDismissAlerts";

    /**
     * Use native intruments lib (ie disable instruments-without-delay).
     */
    String NATIVE_INSTRUMENTS_LIB = "nativeInstrumentsLib";

    /**
     * (Sim-only) Enable "real", non-javascript-based web taps in Safari.
     * Default: false.
     * Warning: depending on viewport size/ratio this might not accurately tap an element.
     */
    String NATIVE_WEB_TAP = "nativeWebTap";

    /**
     * (Sim-only) (&gt;= 8.1) Initial safari url, default is a local welcome page.
     */
    String SAFARI_INITIAL_URL = "safariInitialUrl";

    /**
     * (Sim-only) Allow javascript to open new windows in Safari. Default keeps current sim
     * setting.
     */
    String SAFARI_ALLOW_POPUPS = "safariAllowPopups";

    /**
     * (Sim-only) Prevent Safari from showing a fraudulent website warning.
     * Default keeps current sim setting.
     */
    String SAFARI_IGNORE_FRAUD_WARNING = "safariIgnoreFraudWarning";

    /**
     * (Sim-only) Whether Safari should allow links to open in new windows.
     * Default keeps current sim setting.
     */
    String SAFARI_OPEN_LINKS_IN_BACKGROUND = "safariOpenLinksInBackground";

    /**
     * (Sim-only) Whether to keep keychains (Library/Keychains) when appium
     * session is started/finished.
     */
    String KEEP_KEY_CHAINS = "keepKeyChains";

    /**
     * Where to look for localizable strings. Default en.lproj.
     */
    String LOCALIZABLE_STRINGS_DIR = "localizableStringsDir";

    /**
     * Arguments to pass to the AUT using instruments.
     */
    String PROCESS_ARGUMENTS = "processArguments";

    /**
     * The delay, in ms, between keystrokes sent to an element when typing.
     */
    String INTER_KEY_DELAY = "interKeyDelay";

    /**
     * Whether to show any logs captured from a device in the appium logs. Default false.
     */
    String SHOW_IOS_LOG = "showIOSLog";

    /**
     * strategy to use to type test into a test field. Simulator default: oneByOne.
     * Real device default: grouped.
     */
    String SEND_KEY_STRATEGY = "sendKeyStrategy";

    /**
     * Max timeout in sec to wait for a screenshot to be generated. default: 10.
     */
    String SCREENSHOT_WAIT_TIMEOUT = "screenshotWaitTimeout";

    /**
     * The ios automation script used to determined if the app has been launched,
     * by default the system wait for the page source not to be empty.
     * The result must be a boolean.
     */
    String WAIT_FOR_APP_SCRIPT = "waitForAppScript";

    /**
     * Number of times to send connection message to remote debugger, to get webview.
     * Default: 8.
     */
    String WEBVIEW_CONNECT_RETRIES = "webviewConnectRetries";

    /**
     * The display name of the application under test. Used to automate backgrounding
     * the app in iOS 9+.
     */
    String APP_NAME = "appName";

    /**
     * Capability to pre-authorize a specific SSL cert in the iOS trust store.
     */
    String CUSTOM_SSL_CERT = "customSSLCert";

    /**
     * The desired capability to specify a length for tapping, if the regular
     * tap is too long for the app under test. The  XCUITest specific capability.
     */
    String TAP_WITH_SHORT_PRESS_DURATION = "tapWithShortPressDuration";

    /**
     * The capability to direct Appium to set the simulator scale.
     * The  XCUITest specific capability.
     */
    String SCALE_FACTOR = "scaleFactor";

    /**
     * This value if specified, will be used to forward traffic from Mac
     * host to real ios devices over USB. Default value is same as port
     * number used by WDA on device.
     * eg: 8100
     */
    String WDA_LOCAL_PORT = "wdaLocalPort";

    /**
     * Whether to display the output of the Xcode command
     * used to run the tests.If this is true,
     * there will be lots of extra logging at startup. Defaults to false
     */
    String SHOW_XCODE_LOG = "showXcodeLog";

    /**
     * Time in milliseconds to pause between installing the application
     * and starting WebDriverAgent on the device. Used particularly for larger applications.
     * Defaults to 0
     */
    String IOS_INSTALL_PAUSE = "iosInstallPause";

    /**
     * Full path to an optional Xcode configuration file that
     * specifies the code signing identity
     * and team for running the WebDriverAgent on the real device.
     * e.g., /path/to/myconfig.xcconfig
     */
    String XCODE_CONFIG_FILE = "xcodeConfigFile";

    /**
     * Password for unlocking keychain specified in keychainPath.
     */
    String KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD = "keychainPassword";

    /**
     * Skips the build phase of running the WDA app.
     * Building is then the responsibility of the user.
     * Only works for Xcode 8+. Defaults to false
     */
    String USE_PREBUILT_WDA = "usePrebuiltWDA";

    /**
     * Sets read only permissons to Attachments subfolder of WebDriverAgent
     * root inside Xcode's DerivedData.
     * This is necessary to prevent XCTest framework from
     * creating tons of unnecessary screenshots and logs,
     * which are impossible to shutdown using programming
     * interfaces provided by Apple
     */
    String PREVENT_WDAATTACHMENTS = "preventWDAAttachments";

    /**
     * Appium will connect to an existing WebDriverAgent,
     * instance at this URL instead of starting a new one.
     * eg : http://localhost:8100
     */
    String WEB_DRIVER_AGENT_URL = "webDriverAgentUrl";

    /**
     * Full path to the private development key exported
     * from the system keychain. Used in conjunction
     * with keychainPassword when testing on real devices.
     * e.g., /path/to/MyPrivateKey.p12
     */
    String KEYCHAIN_PATH = "keychainPath";

    /**
     * Forces uninstall of any existing WebDriverAgent app on device.
     * This can provide stability in some situations. Defaults to false.
     */
    String USE_NEW_WDA = "useNewWDA";

    /**
     * Time, in ms, to wait for WebDriverAgewnt to be pingable. Defaults to 60000ms.
     */
    String WDA_LAUNCH_TIMEOUT = "wdaLaunchTimeout";

    /**
     * Timeout, in ms, for waiting for a resonse from WebDriverAgent. Defaults to 240000ms.
     */
    String WDA_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = "wdaConnectionTimeout";

    /**
     * Apple developer team identifier string.
     * Must be used in conjunction with xcodeSigningId to take effect.
     * e.g., JWL241K123
     */
    String XCODE_ORG_ID = "xcodeOrgId";

    /**
     * String representing a signing certificate.
     * Must be used in conjunction with xcodeOrgId.
     * This is usually just iPhone Developer.
     */
    String XCODE_SIGNING_ID = "xcodeSigningId";

    /**
     * Bundle id to update WDA to before building and launching on real devices.
     * This bundle id must be associated with a valid provisioning profile.
     * e.g., io.appium.WebDriverAgentRunner.
     */
    String UPDATE_WDA_BUNDLEID = "updatedWDABundleId";

    /**
     * Whether to perform reset on test session finish (false) or not (true).
     * Keeping this variable set to true and Simulator running
     * (the default behaviour since version 1.6.4) may significantly shorten the
     * duratiuon of test session initialization.
     * Defaults to true.
     */
    String RESET_ON_SESSION_START_ONLY = "resetOnSessionStartOnly";

    /**
     * Custom timeout(s) in milliseconds for WDA backend commands execution.
     */
    String COMMAND_TIMEOUTS = "commandTimeouts";

    /**
     * Number of times to try to build and launch WebDriverAgent onto the device.
     * Defaults to 2.
     */
    String WDA_STARTUP_RETRIES = "wdaStartupRetries";

    /**
     * Time, in ms, to wait between tries to build and launch WebDriverAgent.
     * Defaults to 10000ms.
     */
    String WDA_STARTUP_RETRY_INTERVAL = "wdaStartupRetryInterval";

    /**
     * Set this option to true in order to enable hardware keyboard in Simulator.
     * It is set to false by default, because this helps to workaround some XCTest bugs.
     */
    String CONNECT_HARDWARE_KEYBOARD = "connectHardwareKeyboard";

    /**
     * Maximum frequency of keystrokes for typing and clear.
     * If your tests are failing because of typing errors, you may want to adjust this.
     * Defaults to 60 keystrokes per minute.
     */
    String MAX_TYPING_FREQUENCY = "maxTypingFrequency";

    /**
     * Use native methods for determining visibility of elements.
     * In some cases this takes a long time.
     * Setting this capability to false will cause the system to use the position
     * and size of elements to make sure they are visible on the screen.
     * This can, however, lead to false results in some situations.
     * Defaults to false, except iOS 9.3, where it defaults to true.
     */
    String SIMPLE_ISVISIBLE_CHECK = "simpleIsVisibleCheck";

    /**
     * Use SSL to download dependencies for WebDriverAgent. Defaults to false.
     */
    String USE_CARTHAGE_SSL = "useCarthageSsl";

    /**
     * Use default proxy for test management within WebDriverAgent.
     * Setting this to false sometimes helps with socket hangup problems.
     * Defaults to true.
     */
    String SHOULD_USE_SINGLETON_TESTMANAGER = "shouldUseSingletonTestManager";

    /**
     * Set this to true if you want to start ios_webkit_debug proxy server
     * automatically for accessing webviews on iOS.
     * The capatibility only works for real device automation.
     * Defaults to false.
     */
    String START_IWDP = "startIWDP";

    /**
     * Enrolls simulator for touch id. Defaults to false.
     */
    String ALLOW_TOUCHID_ENROLL = "allowTouchIdEnroll";

}
Can one install an iOS app during the Appium driver initialization, because I'm not seeing a mobile capability for this. 

https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/remote/MobileCapabilityType.html

I suppose "app" but I don't see it in the actuall class

public interface IOSMobileCapabilityType extends CapabilityType {

    /**
     * (Sim-only) Calendar format to set for the iOS Simulator.
     */
    String CALENDAR_FORMAT = "calendarFormat";

    /**
     * Bundle ID of the app under test. Useful for starting an app on a real device
     * or for using other caps which require the bundle ID during test startup.
     * To run a test on a real device using the bundle ID,
     * you may omit the 'app' capability, but you must provide 'udid'.
     */
    String BUNDLE_ID = "bundleId";

    /**
     * Amount of time in ms to wait for instruments before assuming it hung and
     * failing the session.
     */
    String LAUNCH_TIMEOUT = "launchTimeout";

    /**
     * (Sim-only) Force location services to be either on or off.
     * Default is to keep current sim setting.
     */
    String LOCATION_SERVICES_ENABLED = "locationServicesEnabled";

    /**
     * (Sim-only) Set location services to be authorized or not authorized for app via plist,
     * so that location services alert doesn't pop up. Default is to keep current sim
     * setting. Note that if you use this setting you MUST also use the bundleId
     * capability to send in your app's bundle ID.
     */
    String LOCATION_SERVICES_AUTHORIZED = "locationServicesAuthorized";

    /**
     * Accept all iOS alerts automatically if they pop up.
     * This includes privacy access permission alerts
     * (e.g., location, contacts, photos). Default is false.
     */
    String AUTO_ACCEPT_ALERTS = "autoAcceptAlerts";

    /**
     * Dismiss all iOS alerts automatically if they pop up.
     * This includes privacy access permission alerts (e.g.,
     * location, contacts, photos). Default is false.
     */
    String AUTO_DISMISS_ALERTS = "autoDismissAlerts";

    /**
     * Use native intruments lib (ie disable instruments-without-delay).
     */
    String NATIVE_INSTRUMENTS_LIB = "nativeInstrumentsLib";

    /**
     * (Sim-only) Enable "real", non-javascript-based web taps in Safari.
     * Default: false.
     * Warning: depending on viewport size/ratio this might not accurately tap an element.
     */
    String NATIVE_WEB_TAP = "nativeWebTap";

    /**
     * (Sim-only) (&gt;= 8.1) Initial safari url, default is a local welcome page.
     */
    String SAFARI_INITIAL_URL = "safariInitialUrl";

    /**
     * (Sim-only) Allow javascript to open new windows in Safari. Default keeps current sim
     * setting.
     */
    String SAFARI_ALLOW_POPUPS = "safariAllowPopups";

    /**
     * (Sim-only) Prevent Safari from showing a fraudulent website warning.
     * Default keeps current sim setting.
     */
    String SAFARI_IGNORE_FRAUD_WARNING = "safariIgnoreFraudWarning";

    /**
     * (Sim-only) Whether Safari should allow links to open in new windows.
     * Default keeps current sim setting.
     */
    String SAFARI_OPEN_LINKS_IN_BACKGROUND = "safariOpenLinksInBackground";

    /**
     * (Sim-only) Whether to keep keychains (Library/Keychains) when appium
     * session is started/finished.
     */
    String KEEP_KEY_CHAINS = "keepKeyChains";

    /**
     * Where to look for localizable strings. Default en.lproj.
     */
    String LOCALIZABLE_STRINGS_DIR = "localizableStringsDir";

    /**
     * Arguments to pass to the AUT using instruments.
     */
    String PROCESS_ARGUMENTS = "processArguments";

    /**
     * The delay, in ms, between keystrokes sent to an element when typing.
     */
    String INTER_KEY_DELAY = "interKeyDelay";

    /**
     * Whether to show any logs captured from a device in the appium logs. Default false.
     */
    String SHOW_IOS_LOG = "showIOSLog";

    /**
     * strategy to use to type test into a test field. Simulator default: oneByOne.
     * Real device default: grouped.
     */
    String SEND_KEY_STRATEGY = "sendKeyStrategy";

    /**
     * Max timeout in sec to wait for a screenshot to be generated. default: 10.
     */
    String SCREENSHOT_WAIT_TIMEOUT = "screenshotWaitTimeout";

    /**
     * The ios automation script used to determined if the app has been launched,
     * by default the system wait for the page source not to be empty.
     * The result must be a boolean.
     */
    String WAIT_FOR_APP_SCRIPT = "waitForAppScript";

    /**
     * Number of times to send connection message to remote debugger, to get webview.
     * Default: 8.
     */
    String WEBVIEW_CONNECT_RETRIES = "webviewConnectRetries";

    /**
     * The display name of the application under test. Used to automate backgrounding
     * the app in iOS 9+.
     */
    String APP_NAME = "appName";

    /**
     * Capability to pre-authorize a specific SSL cert in the iOS trust store.
     */
    String CUSTOM_SSL_CERT = "customSSLCert";

    /**
     * The desired capability to specify a length for tapping, if the regular
     * tap is too long for the app under test. The  XCUITest specific capability.
     */
    String TAP_WITH_SHORT_PRESS_DURATION = "tapWithShortPressDuration";

    /**
     * The capability to direct Appium to set the simulator scale.
     * The  XCUITest specific capability.
     */
    String SCALE_FACTOR = "scaleFactor";

    /**
     * This value if specified, will be used to forward traffic from Mac
     * host to real ios devices over USB. Default value is same as port
     * number used by WDA on device.
     * eg: 8100
     */
    String WDA_LOCAL_PORT = "wdaLocalPort";

    /**
     * Whether to display the output of the Xcode command
     * used to run the tests.If this is true,
     * there will be lots of extra logging at startup. Defaults to false
     */
    String SHOW_XCODE_LOG = "showXcodeLog";

    /**
     * Time in milliseconds to pause between installing the application
     * and starting WebDriverAgent on the device. Used particularly for larger applications.
     * Defaults to 0
     */
    String IOS_INSTALL_PAUSE = "iosInstallPause";

    /**
     * Full path to an optional Xcode configuration file that
     * specifies the code signing identity
     * and team for running the WebDriverAgent on the real device.
     * e.g., /path/to/myconfig.xcconfig
     */
    String XCODE_CONFIG_FILE = "xcodeConfigFile";

    /**
     * Password for unlocking keychain specified in keychainPath.
     */
    String KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD = "keychainPassword";

    /**
     * Skips the build phase of running the WDA app.
     * Building is then the responsibility of the user.
     * Only works for Xcode 8+. Defaults to false
     */
    String USE_PREBUILT_WDA = "usePrebuiltWDA";

    /**
     * Sets read only permissons to Attachments subfolder of WebDriverAgent
     * root inside Xcode's DerivedData.
     * This is necessary to prevent XCTest framework from
     * creating tons of unnecessary screenshots and logs,
     * which are impossible to shutdown using programming
     * interfaces provided by Apple
     */
    String PREVENT_WDAATTACHMENTS = "preventWDAAttachments";

    /**
     * Appium will connect to an existing WebDriverAgent,
     * instance at this URL instead of starting a new one.
     * eg : http://localhost:8100
     */
    String WEB_DRIVER_AGENT_URL = "webDriverAgentUrl";

    /**
     * Full path to the private development key exported
     * from the system keychain. Used in conjunction
     * with keychainPassword when testing on real devices.
     * e.g., /path/to/MyPrivateKey.p12
     */
    String KEYCHAIN_PATH = "keychainPath";

    /**
     * Forces uninstall of any existing WebDriverAgent app on device.
     * This can provide stability in some situations. Defaults to false.
     */
    String USE_NEW_WDA = "useNewWDA";

    /**
     * Time, in ms, to wait for WebDriverAgewnt to be pingable. Defaults to 60000ms.
     */
    String WDA_LAUNCH_TIMEOUT = "wdaLaunchTimeout";

    /**
     * Timeout, in ms, for waiting for a resonse from WebDriverAgent. Defaults to 240000ms.
     */
    String WDA_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = "wdaConnectionTimeout";

    /**
     * Apple developer team identifier string.
     * Must be used in conjunction with xcodeSigningId to take effect.
     * e.g., JWL241K123
     */
    String XCODE_ORG_ID = "xcodeOrgId";

    /**
     * String representing a signing certificate.
     * Must be used in conjunction with xcodeOrgId.
     * This is usually just iPhone Developer.
     */
    String XCODE_SIGNING_ID = "xcodeSigningId";

    /**
     * Bundle id to update WDA to before building and launching on real devices.
     * This bundle id must be associated with a valid provisioning profile.
     * e.g., io.appium.WebDriverAgentRunner.
     */
    String UPDATE_WDA_BUNDLEID = "updatedWDABundleId";

    /**
     * Whether to perform reset on test session finish (false) or not (true).
     * Keeping this variable set to true and Simulator running
     * (the default behaviour since version 1.6.4) may significantly shorten the
     * duratiuon of test session initialization.
     * Defaults to true.
     */
    String RESET_ON_SESSION_START_ONLY = "resetOnSessionStartOnly";

    /**
     * Custom timeout(s) in milliseconds for WDA backend commands execution.
     */
    String COMMAND_TIMEOUTS = "commandTimeouts";

    /**
     * Number of times to try to build and launch WebDriverAgent onto the device.
     * Defaults to 2.
     */
    String WDA_STARTUP_RETRIES = "wdaStartupRetries";

    /**
     * Time, in ms, to wait between tries to build and launch WebDriverAgent.
     * Defaults to 10000ms.
     */
    String WDA_STARTUP_RETRY_INTERVAL = "wdaStartupRetryInterval";

    /**
     * Set this option to true in order to enable hardware keyboard in Simulator.
     * It is set to false by default, because this helps to workaround some XCTest bugs.
     */
    String CONNECT_HARDWARE_KEYBOARD = "connectHardwareKeyboard";

    /**
     * Maximum frequency of keystrokes for typing and clear.
     * If your tests are failing because of typing errors, you may want to adjust this.
     * Defaults to 60 keystrokes per minute.
     */
    String MAX_TYPING_FREQUENCY = "maxTypingFrequency";

    /**
     * Use native methods for determining visibility of elements.
     * In some cases this takes a long time.
     * Setting this capability to false will cause the system to use the position
     * and size of elements to make sure they are visible on the screen.
     * This can, however, lead to false results in some situations.
     * Defaults to false, except iOS 9.3, where it defaults to true.
     */
    String SIMPLE_ISVISIBLE_CHECK = "simpleIsVisibleCheck";

    /**
     * Use SSL to download dependencies for WebDriverAgent. Defaults to false.
     */
    String USE_CARTHAGE_SSL = "useCarthageSsl";

    /**
     * Use default proxy for test management within WebDriverAgent.
     * Setting this to false sometimes helps with socket hangup problems.
     * Defaults to true.
     */
    String SHOULD_USE_SINGLETON_TESTMANAGER = "shouldUseSingletonTestManager";

    /**
     * Set this to true if you want to start ios_webkit_debug proxy server
     * automatically for accessing webviews on iOS.
     * The capatibility only works for real device automation.
     * Defaults to false.
     */
    String START_IWDP = "startIWDP";

    /**
     * Enrolls simulator for touch id. Defaults to false.
     */
    String ALLOW_TOUCHID_ENROLL = "allowTouchIdEnroll";

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just using the raw `String` worked

```
caps.setCapability("app",myAbsoluteAppPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use "app" capability type and pass the apk/ipa path. And yes there is class APP in the link shared by you that too on 1st position.Adding screenshot for your reference. You can use in following way:

capabilities.setCapability("app", ipa.getAbsolutePath());

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `app` capability you are looking for is in `MobileCapabilityType.APP` (you can see it in the link you mentioned). So instead of raw string, you can use this constant.